# .text in javascript conflict

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have an object generated via JSON:

```
{
    "notification": [
        {
            "mode": "MOBILE_PUSH",
            "notificationRead": 0,
            "actionTaken": 0,
            "requestJson": {
                "text": "Thisisanannouncement",
                "image": "image_url",
                "NOTIFICATION_ACTION_LINK": "action_link"
            },
            "externalReferenceId": "ref1",
            "notificationId": 0,
            "notificationDetailId": 1,
            "notificationStatus": null
        }
    ]
}
```

Here when i try to access text like `notification.requestJson.text`, yet I get undefined. If i change text to something else its working fine. How do i make it work without changing text to something else?

Comment: `notification[0].requestJson.text` given that for no apparent reason there's an array there.

Comment: the first thing i tried was notification[0].requestJson.text

Comment: you're still missing whatever the variable is called that this object is stored in. otherwise, there's nothing wrong except that you overlooked the array.

Comment: i'll tell u what is happening .text() is a method in jquery which is causing problem i think...if i change "text" to something else it is working

Comment: No, it is not. See other comments I posted in reply to you.

Comment: .text method not cause the issue

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this

```
data = {
    "notification": [
        {
            "mode": "MOBILE_PUSH",
            "notificationRead": 0,
            "actionTaken": 0,
            "requestJson": {
                "text": "Thisisanannouncement",
                "image": "image_url",
                "NOTIFICATION_ACTION_LINK": "action_link"
            },
            "externalReferenceId": "ref1",
            "notificationId": 0,
            "notificationDetailId": 1,
            "notificationStatus": null
        }
    ]
}
console.log(data.notification[0].requestJson.text);
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/m5TDW/)

Comment: .text is a method in jquery which is causing problem i think...if i change "text" to something else it is working

Comment: that is not why it isn't working Abhinav, your property is a string on a completely independent object, it has nothing to do with jQuery. you're missing the variable that this is stored in.

Comment: hence var o = {
    "notification": [
        {
            "mode": "MOBILE_PUSH",
            "notificationRead": 0,
            "actionTaken": 0,
            "requestJson": {
                "text": "Thisisanannouncement",
                "image": "image_url",
                "NOTIFICATION_ACTION_LINK": "action_link"
            },
            "externalReferenceId": "ref1",
            "notificationId": 0,
            "notificationDetailId": 1,
            "notificationStatus": null
        }
    ]
}; o.notification[0].requestJson.text works

Answer (score 4):

You must have this object in some other variable, i guess it might be `obj`,

```
obj.notification[0].requestJson.text
```

In your case `notification` would represent an `array`, so by nature `array` does not have a property called `requestJson`, Hence it is displaying the error.

Answer (score 0):

Your notification is an array not object so you supposed to use:

```
notification[0].requestJson.text
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
console.log(notification[0].requestJson["text"]);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is array structure
 if you write index this will work fine

like this

```
notification[0].requestJson.text
```